# Every Activity of my application is shown as an app on its own

Tags: android, android-activity, icons

Just like the title says, for some reason which I dont understand, Every Activity I create in my application is shown as an icon for an application on the phone's app menu.

Could someone please help me solve this wierd problem?

If you need some code just ask for it (I dont know which code is related with these kind of stuff).

Thanks!

Comment: can you show your manifest file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your manifest remove these lines from all Activities except the one you want to open on:

```
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
```

Example:

```
<activity
    android:name="your.package.name.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <!-- This line declares this Activity as the start point -->
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <!-- This line adds a launcher icon -->
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
    android:name="your.package.name.OtherActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file you must have set launcher intent-filter for all of your activities.. Keep launcher intent-filter only in launcher activity..

Comment: just a coincident that someone posted same answer almost at same time :)